# Old code doesn't work with the new version of PDFMiner

Tags: python, pdfminer

I have "inherited" a program from the former collegue. This program worked fine earlier but doesn't work by me. The reason is that the collegue used an older version of PDFMiner (I don't know which version it was) whereas I have a new version. The code is as follows:

```
filpath=r"...."
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
retstr = StringIO()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
fp = open(filepath,'rb')
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr,device)
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument()
parser.set_document(doc)
doc.set_parser(parser)
doc.initialize('')
```

At first I had the error

```
doc = PDFDocument()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parser'.
```

I changed the line doc = PDFDocument() to doc = PDFDocument(parser). This worked but now I have the error

```
'PDFDocument' object has no attribute 'set_parser'
```

whicht apparently comes from the line doc.set_parser(parser).
What should I do now?

Additional Information: the import line in the old program was

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
```

This doesn't work now, I had to change it to two lines

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE. 
I was able at the end to solve my Problem in a "cheap" way - I installed the old version of pdfminer, so I haven't to change anything in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [docs](https://pdfminer-docs.readthedocs.io/programming.html#basic-usage)?

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice

# Open a PDF file.
fp = open('mypdf.pdf', 'rb')
# Create a PDF parser object associated with the file object.
parser = PDFParser(fp)
# Create a PDF document object that stores the document structure.
# Supply the password for initialization.
document = PDFDocument(parser, password)
# Check if the document allows text extraction. If not, abort.
if not document.is_extractable:
    raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
# Create a PDF resource manager object that stores shared resources.
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
# Create a PDF device object.
device = PDFDevice(rsrcmgr)
# Create a PDF interpreter object.
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
# Process each page contained in the document.
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
```

Copied verbatim from the link.

Comment: Thank You! I have edited my question because I am one step further. Now I don't understand what to do with doc.set_parser(parser). In the docs I see that set_parser was removed in 2013 which is rather odd because the collegue wrote this program in 2018 and it worked then as I said.

Comment: I no longer have access to the machine with pdfminer but perhaps others can help you if you provide the version numbers of python, pdfminer, and perhaps your OS.

Comment: It would be helpful to post how you solved your issue for others who may come across your question looking for answers to a similar problem they have.